# Multi-level CRTP and Initialization

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Val
{
    std::string str;
    void append(const std::string n)
    {
        str += n;
    }
    Val() : str("x")
    {

    }
};

template<typename T>
class base
{
public:
    base(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "Base " << n << "\n";

        // triggers error if not ptr
        print();
    }

    void print()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->impl_print();
    }

    ~base()
    {
        std::cout << "DB\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename V>
class implA : public base<implA<T, V>>
{
    friend class base<implA<T, V>>;
public:
    implA(int n) : base<implA<T, V>>(n)
    {
        std::cout << "implA " << n << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            implVal->append(std::to_string(n));
        }
    }

    ~implA()
    {
        std::cout << "iA\n";
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<V> implVal =  NULL;
    void impl_print()
    {
        if (implVal == NULL)
        {
            implVal = std::make_shared<V>();
        }

        static_cast<T*>(this)->impl_print(*implVal);
    }
};


class classX : public implA<classX, Val>
{
    friend class implA<classX, Val>;
public:
    classX(int n) : implA<classX, Val>(n)
    {
        std::cout << "classX " << n << "\n";
    }

protected:
    void impl_print(Val in)
    {
        std::cout<<"p"<< in.str << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    classX x(2);
    x.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to do some multi-level inheritance where the the arguments to a constructor modify the members of the mid-level during construction. Ran into the problem that implVal hasn't been allocated when base triggers its print, so calls to use its value will cause a runtime error.

Tried to fix that by changing implVal to a pointer and allocating it manually when needed. That allows the internal call to print to work, but when the body of implClass constructor resolves, implClass is null again, as if memory was never allocated. This causes a null ptr error when trying to modify the value. What is going on here?

Comment: The base class _must_ be fully constructed before the derived class executes its constructor body. This problem is similar to issues that you get if calling virtual methods from a constructor. The problem is that `implA` is not yet constructed when `base` constructor is invoked. As a result, `static_cast<T*>(this)->impl_print();` results in calling that method _before_ the object is constructed. It's not surprising that when you attempt to initialize `implVal` in that method, the pointer is subsequently lost -- the shared_ptr was not yet constructed. What you're doing is dangerous.

Comment: I can see that this is an unsafe design but I'm trying to understand what is happening before I go for a different design. Even though implA doesn't exist yet when its impl_print() is called, it still runs the function, as evidenced by it allocating memory which then gets read by the classX impl_print(). If that object doesn't exist, how is classX reading one of it's members? Is it some sort of temporary object that only exists during the funciton call and is removed afterwards?

Comment: Because: _undefined behavior_. You used an object before it was constructed. In this case, it likely results in a memory leak.

Comment: Allocation & construction are not quite the same thing; though construction almost always happens right after allocation. Inside the base constructor, derived class is not constructed yet - although it is already allocated. Thus virtual functions in constructor bind early (like none-virtial functions). CRTP brings the hierarchical polymorphism to compile-time, but it no more supports a duality like early/late binding. It is an explicit pointer/reference cast and - unlike the virtual functions case - the programmer is responsible for code safety. The C++23 **deduced this** can replace CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

```
base(int n)
{
    std::cout << "Base " << n << "\n";

    // triggers error if not ptr
    print();
}

void print()
{
    static_cast<T*>(this)->impl_print();
}
```

this pattern is fundamentally not safe.

Your children are not constructed until *after* your constructor returns, and there is no simple way to run code *after* your children are constructed in C++.

Modifying members of a non-constructed object (or a non-constructed part of an object) is UB.  Don't do it.  Even if it works, it isn't guaranteed to work the next time your compiler detects a change in the moon phase (or other seemingly unrelated reasons).

The best you can do is have a post-construct pattern.  The most-derived class is responsible to call a `post_construct` method.

I am unaware of a way to cleanly enforce that your derived `T` will call post-construct.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the code as posted, you're breaking the rules here.  When the `base` constructor runs, `implA` doesn't exist yet.  Calling any methods of `implA` is therefore UB, hence your crash.

CRTP offers no protection to stop you from doing this (whereas regular classes with `virtual` functions do, for very good reasons).  The solution I use is to have a factory function that constructs the object before calling methods on it.